# Haskell types with coercible representations identical to their C counterparts?

Tags: haskell, ghc, representation, coerce

How can I determine if a Haskell type has an equivalent Coercible instance on a given platform?

I've just been told about [`Coercible`](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.7/20131212-1/ghc-prim/GHC-Prim.html#t:Coercible) in GHC 7.8, which seems great. In that context, I guess an equally good question to solve my specific problem is: Is there a way to interrogate GHC about which pairs of types `a`, `b` there is a `Coercible a b` instance for (on the current platform, say)?

It seems to me that for [`coerce :: Coercible a b => a -> b`](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.7/20131212-1/ghc-prim/GHC-Prim.html#v:coerce) to be useful in a compiler- and platform-agnostic program, one would need to know – preferably only at compile-time, but possibly also explicitly when writing the code – whether a given `Coercible a b` instance exists on the given platform and use a slower non-noop fallback otherwise (by means of CPP, I guess).

**Follow-up question:** Would it make sense for GHC to provide a function

```
coerceOrConvert :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

with the property that `coerceOrConvert f` is

- `coerce` if there is a `Coercible a b` instance for the present GHC version and platform
- `f` if not

I realize this makes little sense for ordinary typeclasses, but `Coercible` seems far from ordinary, so it's hard for me to tell…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically the kind of coercion handled in Haskell comes in two flavors: representational equality (via `newtype` and `Coercible`) and new information about type variables (via `Typeable`). The second type has little to do with runtime representation, so I'll just describe the `Coercible`/`newtype` mechanism.

It's a guarantee that that `newtype` changes only the type information and not the underlying representation, thus if we have (the standard example)

```
newtype Age = Age { unAge :: Int }
```

then we should be able to feel confident that something like

```
instance Num Age where
  Age a + Age b = Age (a + b)
  ...
```

is exactly as quick as `(+)` on `Int` is---i.e. there is no pointer indirection going on behind the scenes. In fact, GHC eliminates the `Age` constructor here with no difficulty. The challenge comes about when we want to do something like

```
map Age :: [Int] -> [Age]
```

since `Int` and `Age` are structurally identical this should be a no-op as well---all we must do is satisfy the type system at compile time and then throw away `map Age` operationally at runtime. Sadly, this isn't the case since the `map` will still traverse our list even if it does nothing at each stage.

In situations where a lot of `newtype`s get thrown around but we also want GHC to produce the tightest compiled code you might see (dangerous, careful) uses of `unsafeCoerce`

```
unsafeCoerce :: [Int] -> [Age]
```

In this case `unsafeCoerce` is "safe" as we know that these two types are runtime identical. Also, since `unsafeCoerce` operates purely at the type level and is a true no-op at runtime we know that unlike `map Age`, `unsafeCoerce` is truly an `O(0)` coercion.

But it's pretty dangerous.

`Coercible` hopes to fix this by allowing instantiations like

```
instance Coercible a b => Coercible [a] [b] where coerce = unsafeCoerce
```

so that the Haskell typeclass machinery allows for `coerce` to be used only when safe, unlike `unsafeCoerce`. To ensure this is the case it must not be possible for malicious instances of `Coercible` to be built. To this end all `Coercible` instances are built by the compiler based off uses of `newtype`.

As a final note, when you truly dive into how `Coercible` works you'll have to understand the new Haskell Role system which allows developers to annotate whether or not a `newtype` should allow for a coercion. This is clearly outlined in [the documentation for the `Coercible` class] (http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.1-rc2/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.0/Data-Coerce.html).

Comment: Thank you. This is very informative, but a question still remains: Is there a (probably platform-dependent) list, or (better yet) a way to generate such a list from GHC, of which standard types `a` and `b` there is a `Coercible a b` instance for? (By "standard types" I probably mean something like "the types specified in the Haskell report", or some subset of that).

Comment: I'll add a more concrete scenario: Fix concrete types `a` and `b`. Suppose I want to write a conversion function `f :: a -> b`. I suspect that with GHC on many platforms, there is a `Coercible a b` instance, but not on all platforms (this could happen, right?). Suppose also there is a general, slow, conversion function `g :: a -> b` that always does the right thing without assuming anything about underlying representations (let's say `g` is in the Haskell report). Can I somehow (using CPP if I must) say "let `f = coerce` whenever there is a `Coercible a b` instance, otherwise let `f = g`"?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. The Haskell Report guarantees that newtypes have the same representation, but doesn't say much else about how things ought to be implemented. You can do things specific to GHC's implementation of Haskell—I think if you look into the internals of the [`reflection`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) package you see this a lot—but those things tend to be highly unsafe. `Coercible` as designed is independent of any actual implementation details—it works entirely off the `newtype` promises.

Comment: I am indeed asking precisely about GHC's specific implementation, and I understand that `Coercible` is independent of implementation details... I guess what I'm asking is: Is there an easily accessible list, with some guarantees that it won't change in a minor version, of which (standard) types are implemented with `newtype` in GHC? Or, alternatively, could it be possibly to ask a specific version of GHC on a specific platform, "hey, do you simply `newtype` *this* standard Haskell type from *this* standard Haskell type?", perhaps by asking for `Coercible` instances? I feel it would be helpful.

Comment: For example, I'd like to go: "Are we running GHC?" If no, do slow conversions. If yes, ask GHC "does *this particular version* on *this particular platform* define `newtype CDouble = CDouble Double` (or, is there a `Coercible CDouble Double` instance)?" If no, do slow conversions. If yes, convert with `coerce`. This sounds really useful for a lot of numerical stuff involving FFI.

Comment: Well, you can be guided by the restriction that `coerce` only works when the `newtype` constructor is in scope. That means that any types which are publicly declared to be `newtype`-equivalent will show up in the docs. Many of the FFI types declared in `Foreign.C.Types` are exactly represented as `newtypes`. If you want to get to the explicit underlying memory then you'll want to explore the unboxed types in `GHC.Exts` but notice that these are explicitly *not* `newtypes`, although GHC may decide during compilation to unbox a type.